# Not finding a way to embed website on magic mirror

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, codemirror

How I can embed a website in my magic mirror display as I am really facing issues doing so or finding the right way to do it. The modules proposed on `magicmirror.builders` didn't work much for me. (iframe, etc.)

Comment: do you want to embed webserver into RPI or webbrowser into GUI of MagicMirror?

Comment: What have you try? what the meaning of "didn't work much for me"? magicmirro.builders provides plenty of APIs for getting data and rendering it the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your site cannot be embedded using iframe modules of MagicMirror, it's because some sites cannot be embedded by iframe.

There are several reasons, one of that is HTTP response header `X-Frame-Options: DENY` by the site makes iframe disable. This is needed for the internet security.

For MagicMirror usage, using WebView instead of iframe may resolve the problem.

I created the module.
https://github.com/Iketaki/MMM-WebView